# Evaluating $\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am very confused by this. I am integrating the function;
$$\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$$
And Wolfram alpha is telling me, the result is;
$$\log{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}
\right)}$$
However, Wolfram Mathematica is telling me that the answer is;
$$\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=-\mathrm{artanh}(\sqrt{x^2+1})$$
Are these two representation equivalent?

Comment: $\operatorname{artanh}$ has a logarithmic representation, so it is likely.

Comment: Their derivatives are equal, so the difference is a constant. [log](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=derivative+log%28x%2F%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2B1%29%2B1%29%29), [arctanh](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+-arctanh%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2B1%29%29).

Comment: You have to be careful with the definition of $\operatorname{arctanh}(x)$ 

The usual definition is

$$\operatorname{arctanh}(x) := \frac{1}{2} \ln{\left( \frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)} $$


The problem is that this makes sense in real world if and only if the inner fraction is positive, i.e.

$$
 \frac{1+x}{1-x} > 0 \iff -1 < x < 1
$$

In your case, Wolfram Alpha tell us that $-\operatorname{arctanh}(\sqrt{x^2+1})$ is a solution, but we know that $\sqrt{x^2+1}\ge 1$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @SewerKeeper If this was a part of a solution to an ODE would we rather consider the Wolfram Alpha representation as above?

Comment: The representation wolfram Alpha gives, i.e. $f \colon (0,+\infty) \to \mathbb R$ defined as $f(x) = \log{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}
\right)}$ is a primitive of the integral for every $x > 0$. 

The fun thing is that the function $g(x) = -\operatorname{arctanh}(\sqrt{x^2+1})$ actually is a primitive of the integrand, but its domain is $\emptyset$.

Comment: @SewerKeeper So I would assume that in an ODE it would make more sense to use $$f(x)=\log{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}\right)}$$ Since it is well defined for $x>0$

Comment: Yes, can you add the ODE on your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, the correct representation is the first one.

If we consider $f\colon (0,+\infty) \to \mathbb R$ defined as

$$
f(x)=\log{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}
\right)}
$$

Then $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ for every $x > 0$.

The second function

$$
g(x) =- \operatorname{arctanh}(\sqrt{x^2+1})
$$

has indead no real domain.

One explanation is that if we consider the function
$$
\tanh(x) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^x - \mathrm{e}^{-x}}{\mathrm{e}^x + \mathrm{e}^{-x}}
$$
the image of  $\tanh$ is the interval $(-1,1)$ therefore its inverse function cannot be evaluated for  $\sqrt{x^2+1}$, because $\sqrt{x^2+1} \ge 1$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$,

Comment: The antiderivative of a function is determined up to a indefinite constant. The constant need not to be real. Particularly for $x\in\mathbb R; x>0$: $$\log\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}-\operatorname{arctanh}\sqrt{x^2+1}=i\frac\pi2.$$ In any practical application this constant will play no role.

Comment: @user This is correct, however the original question is "Are $f$ and $g$ equivalent representations?" and imho the answer is no.
The function $f$ is a well defined real function, while the function $g$ is not, so if he is solving an ODE, the function $f$ is the one who I would call a solution.

Comment: Ok. This boils down to the question "Are the antiderivatives which differ by a constant equivalent?". Let the asker decide what answer to this question suits his/her purposes. In any case I will upvote your answer for bringing the issue up to discussion.

Comment: I would say "If $F_1$ and $F_2$ are two antiderivatives of $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$, then it does exist a costant $c \in \mathbb R$ such that $F_1(x) - F_2(x) = c$ for every $x \in [a,b]$" so the function must be  1) Defined in the same interval 2)Real.

For example I don't think $\ln(-x^2)$ and $-\ln(x^2)$ are two antiderivatives of $-\frac{2}{x} $ even if $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} \ln(-x^2) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} - \ln(x^2) $.

Comment: The question is exactly about the integration constant. Does it really need to be real? Does the constant play any role in your application (after using initial or/and boundary conditions)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another representation:

$$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}} = \int\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}} = -\operatorname{arsinh}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is the short proof of logarithmic presentation of inverse hyperbolic functions (here $\operatorname{arctanh} x$):
$$
x=\tanh y=\frac{e^{y}-e^{-y}}{e^{y}+e^{-y}}\stackrel{z=e^y}=\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}\\
\implies z^2=\frac{1+x}{1-x}\implies 
y\equiv\boxed{\operatorname{arctanh} x=\frac12\log\frac{1+x}{1-x}.}
$$

Comment: The problem is that your definition of $\operatorname{arctanh}$ makes sense if and only if $-1 < x < 1$, and we have $\sqrt{1+x^2}\ge1$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$

Comment: I don't quite understand your point.  This is not "my" definition of $\operatorname{arctanh} x$, it is *the* definition of the function. And if you'd like to have the real function just use: $$\operatorname{arctanh}\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\operatorname{arctanh}\sqrt{1+x^2}+i\frac\pi2.$$

Comment: Yes sorry, what I mean is that  there aren't any $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is inside the domain of $\operatorname{arctanh}$. I think the OP refers to real functions.

Comment: As already said for definite integrals it plays no role as the constant $i\frac\pi2$ will cancel. Besides one can use the *real* function $\operatorname{arctanh}\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ instead.

Comment: In real  context I honestly believe it plays a role, since one should define what it mean by $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} \operatorname{i}$. By the way I would say that the function $-\operatorname{arctanh}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right) $ is a real solution of the problem.

Comment: I would like to add that I am totally convinced on your solution and I agree that the costant makes no role. But I think the author of the original post referred to a real analysis course in which "complex technique" are usually precluded.

Answer (score 0):

The various representations discussed on this page are not only equivalent, but all obtainable from a substitution. You can get Wolfram Alpha's answer from $x=\tan t$, Wolfram Mathematica's from $u^2-x^2=1$ & @NinadMunshi's from $xy=1$.